# angular [hidden] does not work when inside a loop on production

Tags: angular, hidden

I have a weird issue.  I have a loop which iterates over a collection and sets the [hidden] attribute based on a property value in the item of the collection.  Initially all of these values are false.  The is what it looks like

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let cus of customer;let indexMod = index; trackBy:indexMod;">
     <div [hidden]="!cus.displaySub">
```

Initially `displaySub` is false on everything, so it should hide the inner div.  This works fine on my dev environment, however when I deploy this same onto production it shows the second `div` on the first load.  Its the same data which I'm working with, in fact initially I'm forcefully setting it to false.  The other option I can think of is that is somehow the code `let indexMod = index; trackBy:indexMod;` is interferring with the rendering ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `[hidden]` attribute you can try `*ngIf` property.